# Neural Network XOR with 8+ Input nodes

Tags: neural-network, xor, backpropagation

Using a standard backdrop, I can train a network with up to 8 binary inputs to learn XOR. So that's a total of 256 input sets, and the output correctly identifies the 8 input sets with only one of the 8 inputs being 1, the rest being 0.

Layout:

• 8 Inputs;

• 1 Hidden layer with 2 or more nodes;

• Out: 1 node

It will train in approx 500 epochs, less if I use more hidden nodes.

However, I can not get to it train on 9 Input nodes at all, no matter how many hidden nodes I use.

Is there an intrinsic limit of 8 preventing this? I suspect I might need another hidden layer, but wanted to get an insight in to whether it is fundamentally impossible as it is?

Thanks for any clues.

Comment: What are the tools/commands you are using? Your current question is too broad. Also I suggest asking in [link](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: there is nothing "magical" about 8 or 9 inputs. Obviously each additional input doubles amount of possible values , thus increases data needed to train, but besides that - it is just the same problem, with no "big" changes needed.

Comment: @ lejlot Thanks, I wasn't sure if I was missing something, so persevered and found a good set of parameters and tested/solved up to N=20 in less than 100 epochs. (Learning Rate .4, Weights +/- .3, Momentum .6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a 9:2:1 can unequivically solve XOR. If you're unable to find a solution, it's either unsuitable settings, or a problem with the algorithm.

Comment: Yes, thanks, it was unsuitable settings, but after an hour didn't know if I was wasting my time, so stuck at it.